# get sum of 1 column between an array of dates

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to get the sum of `i.cost * r.ratio` "partitioned" somehow between the dates generated in the cte ( if `o.date` is between 2 dates in cte dates) but don't know how. I'm positive that between preceding and following is needed. (The SQL as is returns 1 number at the moment)

```
with recursive dates(x) as (
    select (
        select min(date)
        from occasions
    ) union all
    select date(x, '+7 days')
    from dates
    where x<date('now')
)
select sum(
    case when r.ratio is null then 0.5
        else r.ratio
    end * i.cost
)
from occasions o
left join reversed_occasions ro
    on o.ID = ro.occasionID
left join items i
    on i.occasionID = o.ID
left join ratios r
    on r.itemID = i.ID;
```

the schema used for creating the database is as below:

```
create table if not exists users(
    ID integer primary key,
    user text
);
create table if not exists categories(
    ID integer primary key,
    category text
);
create table if not exists items(
    ID integer primary key,
    categoryID integer
        not null
        references categories(ID),
    cost float
        not null,
    occasionID integer
        not null
        references occasions(ID)
);
create table if not exists ratios(
    itemID integer
        not null
        references items(ID),
    ratio float
        not null
);
create table if not exists comments(
    itemID integer
        not null
        references items(ID),
    comment text
);
create table if not exists occasions(
    ID integer primary key,
    log datetime
        default current_timestamp,
    date date
        default current_date
);
create table if not exists reversed_occasions(
    occasionID integer
        not null
        references occasions(ID)
);
create view if not exists data as
select o.log,
    o.date,
    case when ro.occasionID is null then (
        select user from users where ID = 1
    ) else (
        select user from users where ID = 2
    )
    end as user,
    ca.category, 
    case when r.ratio is null then 0.5
        else r.ratio
    end as ratio,
    i.cost,
    co.comment
from occasions o
left join reversed_occasions ro
    on o.ID = ro.occasionID
left join items i
    on i.occasionID = o.ID
left join ratios r
    on r.itemID = i.ID
left join comments co
    on co.itemID = i.ID
left join categories ca
    on ca.ID = i.categoryID;
```

output of `view data` for 1 month

```
select *
from data
where date between '2021-08-01'
and '2021-09-01'
and category = 'cat_name1';

2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    -4.8
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.48
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.59
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.6
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.82
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.95
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.99
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.0
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.18
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.29
2021-08-05 18:45:09  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    2.78
2021-08-05 18:48:29  2021-08-05  username1  cat_name1     0.5    4.8
2021-08-06 21:02:53  2021-08-06  username1  cat_name1     0.5    7.98
2021-08-07 11:42:17  2021-08-07  username1  cat_name1     1.0    16.27
2021-08-07 11:42:17  2021-08-07  username1  cat_name1     0.8    17.97
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    -0.89
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.16
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.28
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.69
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.95
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.95
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.98
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.02
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.03
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.18
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.29
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.54
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.79
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    2.89
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    2.95
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    3.05
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     1.0    4.05
2021-08-08 10:44:20  2021-08-08  username1  cat_name1     0.5    4.89
2021-08-09 11:16:02  2021-08-09  username1  cat_name1     0.0    7.58
2021-08-12 15:37:54  2021-08-12  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.62
2021-08-12 15:37:54  2021-08-12  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.34
2021-08-12 15:37:54  2021-08-12  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.35
2021-08-12 15:37:54  2021-08-12  username1  cat_name1     0.0    1.69
2021-08-12 15:37:54  2021-08-12  username1  cat_name1     0.5    2.0
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.19
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.8
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.89
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.18
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.19
2021-08-15 11:08:34  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.96
2021-08-15 11:11:08  2021-08-15  username1  cat_name1     0.0    4.64
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    -2.9
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.15
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.28
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.45
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.67
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.94
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.94
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.95
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.95
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.95
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.98
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.02
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.21
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.29
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.5
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.54
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.59
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.65
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     1.0    2.95
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    4.89
2021-08-19 19:59:52  2021-08-19  username1  cat_name1     0.7    5.49
2021-08-20 16:56:16  2021-08-20  username2  cat_name1     0.5    3.6
2021-08-20 16:58:37  2021-08-20  username1  cat_name1     0.5    -1.92
2021-08-20 16:58:37  2021-08-20  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.89
2021-08-20 16:58:37  2021-08-20  username1  cat_name1     0.5    3.6
2021-08-20 16:58:37  2021-08-20  username1  cat_name1     0.5    5.9
2021-08-22 19:14:58  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.45
2021-08-22 19:14:58  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.8
2021-08-22 19:14:58  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     0.7    0.98
2021-08-22 19:14:58  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.18
2021-08-22 19:14:58  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     0.7    1.79
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.3
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.86
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.89
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.24
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    1.59
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    2.59
2021-08-22 19:21:08  2021-08-22  username1  cat_name1     1.0    2.69
2021-08-28 13:29:15  2021-08-27  username2  cat_name1     0.5    0.8
2021-08-28 13:29:15  2021-08-27  username2  cat_name1     1.0    1.09
2021-08-28 13:30:28  2021-08-23  username2  cat_name1     0.5    1.18
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     1.0    0.17
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.5    0.59
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.5    0.59
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.5    0.8
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    0.89
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     1.0    0.98
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.5    0.98
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    1.02
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     1.0    1.03
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    1.19
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     1.0    1.2
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.5    1.35
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    1.5
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    2.69
2021-08-28 13:34:01  2021-08-25  username2  cat_name1     0.7    4.89
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    -4.85
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.21
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.24
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.35
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.45
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     1.0    0.56
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.84
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    0.98
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.19
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.0    1.2
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    1.35
2021-08-30 17:21:36  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    2.49
2021-08-30 17:21:49  2021-08-30  username1  cat_name1     0.5    5.9
```

results should be something like:

```
2021-08-01 @RESULT
2021-08-08 @RESULT
2021-08-15 @RESULT
2021-08-22 @RESULT
2021-08-29 @RESULT
```

where `@RESULT` is `i.cost*r.ratio` between the date seen on the left of @RESULT and the date found on the next line

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right after a brief break from my project..
I also group by category in addition to my original request.

```
with recursive dates(x) as (
    select (
        select min(date)
        from occasions
    ) union all
    select date(x, '+7 days')
    from dates
    where x < date('now')
)
select ds.x, category, sum(cost) from data dd
left join dates ds on (dd.date between ds.x and date(ds.x, '+6 days') )
group by ds.x, category;
```